# Insert google experiment code only on non mobile browers using javascript

Tags: javascript, responsive-design, variant

I currently have a site that uses `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no, maximum-scale=1.0" />` to make the page responsive.

The issue I am trying to overcome is using google variant testing on two versions of the homepage, but only having people viewing the full site included.

My proposed solution would be to detect whether the browser is a mobile device and if not display the analytic code:

```
<!-- Google Analytics Content Experiment code -->
<script>function utmx_section(){}function utmx(){}(function(){var
k='13292219-1',d=document,l=d.location,c=d.cookie;
if(l.search.indexOf('utm_expid='+k)>0)return;
function f(n){if(c){var i=c.indexOf(n+'=');if(i>-1){var j=c.
indexOf(';',i);return escape(c.substring(i+n.length+1,j<0?c.
length:j))}}}var x=f('__utmx'),xx=f('__utmxx'),h=l.hash;d.write(
'<sc'+'ript src="'+'http'+(l.protocol=='https:'?'s://ssl':
'://www')+'.google-analytics.com/ga_exp.js?'+'utmxkey='+k+
'&utmx='+(x?x:'')+'&utmxx='+(xx?xx:'')+'&utmxtime='+new Date().
valueOf()+(h?'&utmxhash='+escape(h.substr(1)):'')+
'" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"><\/sc'+'ript>')})();
</script><script>utmx('url','A/B');</script>
<!-- End of Google Analytics Content Experiment code -->
```

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking but browser checks at client-side is not reliable so you better handle it server-side.

Answer (score 0):

> My proposed solution would be to detect whether the browser is a mobile device and if not display the analytic code:

One approach is to use the `javascript` equivalent of CSS `@media queries`, which is

```
window.matchMedia();
```

A standard CSS `@media query` to detect a mobile browser might be:

```
@media only screen and (min-device-width:320px) and (max-device-width:480px)
```

The `javascript` equivalent would be:

```
window.matchMedia("(min-device-width:320px) and (max-device-width:480px)");
```

So you could have something like:

```
var screen320x480 = window.matchMedia("(min-device-width:320px) and (max-device-width:480px)");
var screen320x568 = window.matchMedia("(min-device-width:320px) and (max-device-width:568px)");

if ((screen320x480.matches) || (screen320x568.matches)) {

[...CODE HERE...]

}

else {

[...DISPLAY ANALYTICS CODE HERE...]

}
```

**Further Reading:**

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/matchMedia
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Testing_media_queries

Comment: How would I put the code in? the else bit, just plonk it in?

Comment: That's the first thing I would try (after removing `<script>` & `</script>`), yes.

Comment: This didn't work, it must be something to do with the way the analytics code is constructed.

Comment: Yes it could be - did you run a test using console.log or window.alert to verify that the matchMedia part of the script was working?

Comment: I have tested the matchMedia part and it is working, I just can't get the analytic code to place properly.